# Open LDAP implementation for SSO in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, openldap, adfs2.0

Kind of weird to ask this question, I have successfully implement SSO for ASP.NET MVC with ADFS 2.0 on Windows Server 2008 R2, now my Web App needs to authenticate to another LDAP implementation which is Open-LDAP which is on non-windows platform basically a domain controller on linux. I am still not clear in my approach as if this is possible to implement SSO other then windows server Active Directory.

Please suggest an approach to implement the solution as the authentication will be on Open-LDAP.

Any reference implementation is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

ADFS can only authenticate against AD.

The next version on Server 2016 will be able to authenticate against Open-LDAP.

In the meantime, your only option is to federate ADFS with another IDP that can do this e.g. shibboleth.

Comment: thanks for reply can you please reference some implementation code & scenario which can help me ... mean while i have authenticated open-ldap using ldapconnect now problem remain is SSO for my asp.net web api App to work on all the domain users workstations with any user/password input.